# Should I worry about other sites "stealing" SE content?

Tags: discussion, policy, licensing

Googling a phrase from [Which font is the most comfortable for on-screen viewing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20149/which-font-is-the-most-comfortable-for-on-screen-viewing) brings up three other sites featuring the same question:

1. www.faqoverflow.com/tex/20149.html
2. www.zqna.net/qna/ihnmrw-which-font-is-the-most-comfortable-for-on-screen-viewing.html
3. www.techques.com/question/31-20149/Which-font-is-the-most-comfortable-for-on-screen-viewing

<sup>Hyperlinks removed by doncherry so that bots don’t think these links are worth following, cf. [meta.so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131846/162565).</sup>

I knew that all SE user content is "licensed" under something called "cc-wiki license", which, as [the SE blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)  explains, requires that the re-user

1. Shows that content is from SE and hyperlinks to the original question,
2. Shows the question/answer/comment posters' names and hyperlinks to their SE profiles.

FAQ Overflow fulfills these requirements, while the other two don't. So what can/should we do?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

They can be reported on Meta Stack Overflow - ZQNA was already added by @doncherry:

[Report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here)